# Api request dynamically assign the variable value

Tags: python, api, escaping

This is the python script. I want to dynamically call the parameter value. example

```
s1=str('345')
value="+s1+" 
print(value)
```

i want the output as "345". Can anyone help me how to assign the value variable to "345".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use format strings:

```
s1=str('345')
value="+{}+".format(s1) 
print(value)
```

Or python 3.6+ f-strings:

```
s1=str('345')
value=f"+{s1}+" 
print(value)
```

Or concatenation:

```
s1=str('345')
value="+"+s1+"+" 
print(value)
```